# Practice at localhost contains obsolete methods, Reason: the virtual machine was unable to remove all stack frames running old code

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, hot-code-replace

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVfS1.png)

My code runs without problem but this prompt keeps appearing. I have run into this problem a lot but I just ignored it since the code runs fine. However it's starting to get rather annoying and all the fixes I saw online did not work. I suspect this has something to do with 'hot code replace'.

I also did set "Build automatically".

I saw on some other post that I could disable hot code replace by going to Preferences>Run/Debug, but I found no such option.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You get that when you _debug_ your code, but not when you _run_ it, right? Do you only get this if you change code while debugging? Which Java VM do you use exactly? Do you get that even with a "Hello World" application without dependencies and without having a breakpoint set?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was running in debug, I confused my shortcut keys... Problem fixed lol